# While loop inside a function for R

Tags: r, function, while-loop

I'm a bit of a beginner with R, but I do have some experience with other languages like Python.

While I'm aware that there are packages that can do what I'm trying to do for me, I want to really get to grips with this programming language. What I'm trying to do is create a simulation of an M/M/1 queue, and decided that a while loop would work. However, I'm a little stuck and hoping to get some help.

```
# M/M/1 queue simulator

lambda <- 2         # arrival rate
mu <- 3             # service rate
duration <- 10000   # total T of the simulation
t <- 0              # current time in the simulation
queue <- 0          # start with empty queue
s <- 0              # running sum for computing average queue length

# first arrival to start process

T1 <- rexp(1,rate=lambda)
currentqueue <- 1
eventsTime <- T1
t <- T1
nEvents <- 1        # total number of events that have occurred


sims <- function(lambda, mu, duration, t, queue, s) 
{
    while (t<duration) {
        nEvents <- nEvents+1
        if(currentqueue>0) { 
            T1 <- rexp(1,rate=lambda+mu) 

        p <- runif(1,0,1)
        queue[nEvents] <- currentqueue 
        currentqueue <- ifelse(p<lambda/(lambda+mu),
                             currentqueue+1, 
                             currentqueue-1) 
    } else { 
        T1 <- rexp(1,rate=lambda)
        queue[nEvents] <- currentqueue
        currentqueue <- 1
    }
    t <- t+T1 
    eventsTime[nEvents] <- T1 
    s <- s+T1*queue[nEvents] 
  }
}

sims(2,3,10000,0,0,0)   #tests the function with given parameters
```

The while loop by itself works fine and simulates an M/M/1 queue, when given the parameters for lambda, mu, duration, t, queue, and s. Lots of data gets generated from the simulation and put into eventsTime. However, when I attempt to put this into:

```
sims <- function(lambda, mu, duration, t, queue, s) {}
```

I have trouble. The function is stored - when I check for "sims", it's right there. However, the test parameters I put in don't spit out any simulated data despite R Studio clearly performing some calculations.

Any advice?

Comment: Generally in R we don't write functions in a way that has side effects. i.e. we don't write functions that modify variables _outside_ the function, which is what you seem to be trying to do. As a result, your function `sims` doesn't explicitly return any values, and everything you do inside the function only modifies values within the scope of the function, not elsewhere. You should maybe read some basic tutorials on writing functions in R, which would cover this concept.

Answer (score 2):

Your sims function doesn't explicitly return a value, so the value returned is the last value calculated. (That behavior makes sense, since a function like function(x) x^3 ought to return x cubed whenever possible.) In the case of sims, that value is the value of the while loop, and while loops evaluate to `NULL`.

```
> x <- 0
> a <- while(x < 100) x <- x + 1
> a
NULL
```

As a result, sims will always return `NULL`:

```
> sims.demo <- function() { x <- 0 ; while(x < 100) x <- x + 1 }
> a <- sims.demo()
> a
NULL
```

Return `eventsTime` and I think you'll get what you want.

Comment: What if I wanted to simulate the queue multiple times to get lots of different eventsTime values?  I didn't make that clear from the beginning, so I apologise.

Comment: You'll have filled that array in at the end of the while loop, so returning it will give you the eventsTime values. If you want many eventsTime arrays, loop over sims.

Comment: Just for reference, the code you've written will have terrible performance. R is copy on write, so each time you add a new value with the `eventsTime[nEvents]` assignment, you copy the entire `eventsTime` array. You'd do a lot better to use a native iterator like sapply or vapply.

Comment: I think that a well-placed Reduce could easily replace that while loop as well.