# Writing a WHILE Loop until all conditions are satisfied

Tags: r

I have the following matrix representing colors [e.g. 1=red, 2=blue, 3 = green, 4 = yellow, 5 = orange) - (1,1) is the probability of going from red to red, (1,2) is the probability of going from red to blue, etc.]:

```
set.seed(123)

transition_matrix <- matrix(nrow = 5, ncol = 5)

for(i in 1:5) {
    transition_matrix[i,] <- runif(5)
    transition_matrix[i,] <- transition_matrix[i,] / sum(transition_matrix[i,])
}
```

The matrix looks like this:

```
           [,1]       [,2]       [,3]      [,4]       [,5]
[1,] 0.08692491 0.23827784 0.12361982 0.2669061 0.28427129
[2,] 0.01841313 0.21345092 0.36070003 0.2228803 0.18455562
[3,] 0.34626521 0.16405558 0.24520376 0.2072284 0.03724707
[4,] 0.36424312 0.09961467 0.01702542 0.1327401 0.38637668
[5,] 0.22968745 0.17888838 0.16538491 0.2567298 0.16930943

# check to see if all rows sum to 1:

data.frame(row_number = 1:nrow(transition_matrix), row_sum = apply(transition_matrix, 1, sum))
```

I am trying to accomplish the following tasks:

- Problem 1: Given that we start with a random color, how many random draws will it take to see each color at least once? (then repeat this 1000 times)
- Problem 2: Given that we start with a random color, how many random draws will it take to see the colors in order, i.e. 1,2,3,4,5

I have written simple WHILE loops before, but I am not sure how to account for multiple conditions.

I read online (e.g. [While loop inside a function for R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42303721/while-loop-inside-a-function-for-r)) and found out about the ALL() function in R. Here is what I tried:

```
# Problem 1:

# Initialize 
num_steps <- numeric(1000)

# Repeat  1000 times
for(j in 1:1000) {
    # Initialize the state vector
    state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = rep(0.2, 5))
    
    # initialize a vector to keep track of visited states
    visited_states <- rep(FALSE, 5)
    
    # Initialize  counter
    iterations <- 0
    
    # first while
    while(!all(visited_states)) {
        # current
        visited_states[state] <- TRUE
        
        # Transition
        state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = transition_matrix[state,])
        
        # Increment tcounter
        iterations <- iterations + 1
    }
    
    # Record the number of steps 
    num_steps[j] <- iterations
}

print(num_steps)
```

And here is Problem 2:

```
num_steps <- numeric(1000)


for(j in 1:1000) {
    
    state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = rep(0.2, 5))
    
 
    path <- numeric(0)
    
    
    iterations <- 0
    
    # simulate until states 1,2,3,4,5 are visited in order
    while(TRUE) {
     
        path <- c(path, state)
        
        state <- sample(1:5, size = 1, prob = transition_matrix[state,])
        
        iterations <- iterations + 1
        
        # termination condition for while statement
        if(length(path) >= 5 && all(tail(path, 5) == 1:5)) {
            break
        }
    }
    
    
    num_steps[j] <- iterations
}


print(num_steps)
```

The code seems to be running and producing logical outputs, but I am not sure if I am doing this correctly. Is this the correct use of WHILE statements for multiple conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a simpler approach of only tracking the unique values found.  Create an empty found set and when a unique value is chosen add it to the set.  Once the set is filled with the maximum number of unique values stop.

I will leave to the read to adjust the probabilities in the `sample()` function.

```
#initialize values
foundset <- vector()
iteration <-0

while (length(foundset) < 5) {
   #increment iteration
   iteration <- iteration +1
   #pick a new number
   pick <- sample(1:5, 1)
   #see if pick in the set if not add it
   if (!(pick %in% foundset)) {
      foundset <- c(foundset, pick)
   }
   #exit if all five values are found
}

print(iteration)
print(foundset)
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! can this approach be used for both problems?

Comment: btw- was my original attempt correct?

Comment: Yes, you could wrap this into your thousand trial loop.  The original approach looks fine.  The second approach is growing the vector "path" inside a loop which could become a problem, if the vector grows too large.